What common proverb does this string refer to?
What common proverb is referenced by this three-character string?
ᚷᛖᚨ

rot13(Natyb-Fnkba eharf zrnavat Tvsg Fgrrq Nfu-gerr?  V jnag gb fnl, arire ybbx n tvsg ubefr va gur zbhgu, ohg gung'f whfg abg evtug.)

@lulu rot13(Cyrnfr erfcbaq jvgu gung nf na nafjre - vg vf jung V vagraqrq. Zl fbhepr zngrevny jnf n ivqrb naq V qbhoyr-purpxrq hfvat n frnepu ratvar naq Jvxvcrqvn. Gubfr jbeqf ner npprcgrq anzrf sbe gubfr eharf - cyrnfr sbetvir gur snpg V qvqa'g hfr flzobyf sbe "arire" be "ybbx")

hg V pna'g pbzceruraq gur nfu-gerr cneg.

Nabgure anzr sbe gung ehar vf "zbhgu" (nppbeqvat gb Jvxvcrqvn)

Nu, abg snzvyvne jvgu gung ernqvat.  Jvyy cbfg.

Suggest [tag:runes] do we need one ?

FYI here is a breakdown of the character family  Some subtle differences there...and it's not like the folk who used them held to formally established standards.


  Don't Look A Gift Horse in the Mouth.  These are Anglo Saxon Runes which I recognize as meaning "Gift, Steed, Ash-Tree"  The OP assures me that the final, aesch, from which we get our word "ash", can also mean Mouth.


Excellent! I used Wikipedia, but in particular this video for reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4npuVmGxXuk

(at the 11:59 mark)
